# MongoDB auto-increment counter document with Doctrine ODM

Tags: doctrine-odm

I need an auto-incrementing field in MongoDB. 
I've found [documentation on how to use a counter-collection in MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/).

However, my value id NOT the _id, it in not necessarily set and I need to use this through Doctrine ODM (which I am rather unfamiliar with). How do I use a counter-collection through Doctrine ODM?

Answer (score 3):

Not quite what I was hoping for, but doing it in two steps is the only solution I've found:

```
$counter = $dm->createQueryBuilder('Documents\Counter')
->findAndUpdate()
->returnNew()
->field('name')->equals('order_number')
->field('count')->inc(1)
->getQuery()
->execute();
```

Then use the returned value in the other document:

```
$order = $dm->getRepository('Documents\Order')->findOneBy(array('id' => <some_id>));
$order->setOrderNumber($counter->getCount());
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I don't have enough point to comment. You can have an auto increment field without using counter collection. You can use `INCREMENT` [Doctrine Annotation marker](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#introduction-to-docblock-annotations) for your feild variable in Doctrine mongoDB document class. 
see here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifiers

Comment: in cakePhp I also struggled to generate autoincrement but later I cam to know that for scalable database with large number of document, it's not advisable. 

**"Warning
Generally in MongoDB, you would not use an auto-increment pattern for the _id field, or any field, because it does not scale for databases with large numbers of documents. Typically the default value ObjectId is more ideal for the _id.** http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/